# Location of iPhone backup

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard

Where does iTunes backup (location) iPhone data on Mac Snow Leopard.
Cannot fine `MobileSync\backup` in `~/Library/Application Support/`

Comment: 1 Google search is all you needed to find that out.

Comment: I google'd and was not able to find right answer my situtation.  Even though i backup my iphone it doesnt create any Mobile Backups @ /Users/<ComputerName>/Library/iTunes/.  Whoever marked it as -ve seems lack of knowledge to analyse my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find iPhone back up `/Users/<ComputerName>/Library/iTunes/Mobile Backups`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like previous iTunes versions (probably with Snow Leopard) backups were in 
Users/Name/iTunes/Mobile Backups.
Now there stored users/name/library/application support/mobilesync/backup.

I would assume the older Users/Name/iTunes/Mobile Backups could be deleted if you see
backups also in users/name/library/application support/mobilesync/backup.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion may be in the fact that there are more than one Library folders that contain Application Support folders.  The path you want is the /Library/Application Support/ that are contained within your User folder then your home folder (named with your username).

Users/***_*___**/Library/Application Support/MobileSync\backup

Answer (score 0):

OSX 10.6.8 and iTunes 11 in August 2013, open itunes, go to preferences, navigate to the devices tab and right click on the backup you want to "Show in Finder" voila!

for me it's users > [username] > library > Application Support > Mobilesync

like it's been for years now.